# Configuring multiple modules for CLI deployment (eb deploy) for AWS ElasticBeanstalk is not working

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on a Laravel project. I am trying to deploy my application to the ElasticBeanstalk environment. I am configuring the CLI for the deployment. I could configure it just for one environment successfully. But I am configuring it to support multiple modules for multiple environments as mentioned here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebcli-compose.html. But it is not working. Here is what I have done so far.

I created two folders called, beanstalk-env-production and beanstalk-env-testing right inside the project's root folder.

Then I run the following command.

```
eb init --modules beanstalk-env-testing beanstalk-env-production
```

Then .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file is created within each folder.

The config.yml files have the following content.

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: MyanEat-test-env
environment-defaults:
  MyanEat-test-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: Myan Eat
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-1::platform/PHP 7.3 running on
    64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3
  default_region: eu-west-1
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

Then I run the following command to deploy to testing.

```
eb deploy --modules beanstalk-env-testing
```

Then I got the following error.

```
All specified modules require an env.yaml file.
The following modules are missing this file: beanstalk-env-testing
```

Where and how can I configure env.yaml file? Why is it not working? How can I fix it?

Comment: According to the docs you have to run `eb create` to create the enviroments before you run `eb deploy`, did you do this?

Comment: Hi. I already have the environment. I have deployed it. Now I am just trying to separate the environments into modules.

Comment: when you created the environment the first time, did it create the `.env.yaml` file?

Comment: No. I don't see that. I only see config.yaml files.